# flask , breaking query?

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlite

```
@app.route('/getEmployees/<userid>')
def all(userid):
    for i in range (0,200000,50):
            g.db = connect_db()
            cur=g.db.execute('select * from employees limit 50 offset '+ str(i))
            entry=[dict(emp_no=row[0],birth_date=row[1],first_name=row[2],last_name=row[3],gender=row[4],hire_date=row[5]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
            g.db.close()
            return str(entry)
```

So I want to return all employees in blocks of 50. The database has 200,000 entries. using the return statement this way will return only first 50 entries and exit the function. how do I implement this logic in another way?

Comment: Do you want all blocks on the first call or do you want the *next* block of 50 on the successive call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [Flask sessions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions) to keep track of the last offset that was used during the last request.

```
from flask import session, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/getEmployees/<userid>')
def all(userid):

    # Allow the user to specify an offset via querystring
    offset = request.args.get('offset')

    # Allow user to specify limit but default to 50
    limit = request.args.get('limit', 50)

    if offset is None:
        # Look in the session and default to 0 if not defined
        offset = session.get('offset', 0)

    # Do your query
    g.db = connect_db()
    cur = g.db.execute('select * from employees limit %d offset %d' % (limit, int(offset)))
    entry = [dict(emp_no=row[0],birth_date=row[1],first_name=row[2],last_name=row[3],gender=row[4],hire_date=row[5]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    g.db.close()

    # Store the current offset in the session so it is available next request
    session['offset'] = offset + limit;

    return str(entry)
```

You can then query it in the following way.

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()

s.get('http://localhost/getEmployees/1')                    # Get first 50
s.get('http://localhost/getEmployees/1')                    # Get next 50

params = {'offset': 0};
s.get('http://localhost/getEmployees/1', params=params)     # Get First 50
```

Comment: hey man i am only getting the first 50 everytime i run requests.get('http://localhost/getEmployees/1') It works fine on my web browser though , any idea?

Comment: @rohit Sorry about that, just updated the example at the end. Had to switch to `requests.Session()` to ensure session data is preserved between calls.